# White screen of death when uploading a file attachment

Tags: files

I am currently experiencing a problem when adding file attachments to nodes in Drupal 6. When attaching a file and clicking the upload button, the screen goes white. I checked the files directory and the file does not appear there so it would seem it never gets uploaded. This problem occurs on the production server but not the test server. I have tried displaying php errors by modifying the index.php file but that does not display anything. I have the php memory set to 154MB but still no dice. I have Googled and searched this site but can't find a solution. Has anyone else experienced this problem? Can anyone provide some insight as to what the cause of this might be (and hopefully how to fix it)?

System setup

Ubuntu 10.4,
Apache,
PHP 5.3,
MySQL 5.1

Drupal 6.22,
CKK 6.x-2.9,
jQuery UI 6.x-1.5,
jQuery Update 6.x-2.0-alpha1,
plus a whole boatload of other modules (that may or may not be relevant).

Thanks for any possible insight into this.

Comment: Doing some more digging in the error logs, I came across this message: mod_fcgid: HTTP request length 133640 (so far) exceeds MaxRequestLen. A possible solution to this problem is to update the Apache vhost configuration file and add the FcgidMaxRequestLen directive with a big enough value (in bytes), for example

FcgidMaxRequestLen 2000000

which equals roughly 2 MB. Then restart Apache. I will give this a go and see what happens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[mod_fcgid](http://httpd.apache.org/mod_fcgid/) have to do with FastCGI.

There are actually a few PHP settings you may need to investigate and modify.

Reference: [Increase upload size in your php.ini](http://drupal.org/node/97193)

In short though, you will need to up your `upload_max_filesize` as well as your `post_max_size`

Also, I would recommend watching your /var/log/apache2/error.log (Default location in Ubuntu 10.4) while debugging.  Generally running `sudo tail -f /var/log/apache2/error.log` will show you 'white screen' errors in real time.